# Choppy animation while scrolling up in safari and FireFox

Tags: jquery, firefox, safari, web-frontend

I am building a website where i have put a scroll animation in which an icon images moves up based on the offset position of the right container content. The logic works great but the animation is choppy in safari and Firefox.

URL - http://ashirvad.xyz/qbf/

Code logic goes something like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var height = $(window).height(),
        scroll = $(window).scrollTop()
        var offsetStart = $('#cardContent').offset();      
    if (initialOffSetStartPosition.top >= (offsetStart.top -scroll - 1) ) {
        $(".nav-sticky").offset({top:offsetStart.top});     
}
});
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `transform` instead of positioning.
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/

It has better performance and may give you smoother results. Also, if you are on a retina display, or other high density display, it can also affect performance.

UPDATE: Yeah, I just tried it on a 5K monitor in Safari and Firefox and the performance was bad. But, when I moved it over to a standard monitor, the performance was fine. I still say use `transform` over positioned elements for animation quality, though.

Answer (score 1):

1. Do not animate properties that trigger layout recalculation. In short, use `transform` instead of positioning props like `top` `left` etc. Check [here](https://csstriggers.com/) to see how each property works. In general, `transform` and `opacity` are the only properties that can be animated cheaply, the rest depends on exact layout complexity.
2. Unless you're scaling the moved elements, you can pre-optimize them with `will-change: transform`. It's a [complicated](https://greensock.com/will-change) topic, but in general it helps at least as well as setting a blank initial transform with something like `translateZ(0)`.
3. Make the scroll bind [passive](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/passive-event-listeners).

Comment: #2 tried already with no success. Again the issue is only in safari and fireFox . chrome works fine. 
#3 i am not sure that safari even supports it.

Comment: #1 it is the design requirement from client. I can't change it.

Comment: If you can't do #1, you can't fix it. That is the direct cause of the problem, so if using exact style properties is a client requirement, he's breaking it himself.